# Math software to generate stereographic projection of polyhedra

Tags: reference-request, math-software, polyhedra, projection, stereographic-projections

Is there any software to generate the stereographic projection of polyhedra?

Note that since the stereographic projection is infinite, it should take a viewing window as an input.

(In my particular application, I am trying to find stereographic projections of goldberg polyhedra, and only need slightly more than a hemisphere. Also, it would be best if was free and/or open source.)

EDIT: Wikimedia commons has a [list of stereographic projections of polyhedra](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Stereographic_projections_of_polyhedra), but doesn't explain how they were generated.

EDIT: [This](https://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/?recipe=A10cccD&palette=%23ff7777%20%23aaaaaa) comes close to what I'm looking for, but it uses orthogonal instead of stereographic projection.

EDIT: I actually know how to generate stereographically project a single point onto a plane, and how to make images that way. My trouble is finding the coordinates of the vertices of polyhedra in terms of Conway notation.

Comment: Check out [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @g.kov That link appears to be dead.

Comment: "The sourceforge.net website is temporarily in static offline mode."
You can check [CTAN](https://ctan.org/search/?phrase=asymptote) meanwhile.

Comment: There is also a copy on [github](https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote)

Comment: The link you posted has a further link to its source code on github - https://github.com/levskaya/polyhedronisme - which appears to construct the full $(x,y,z)$ coordinates of all vertices. Of course to display it, some projection must be chosen, but if you can understand the code you can make it stereographic.

Comment: @DavidK I unfortunately do not know how to use the programming language in that repo.

Comment: http://www.georgehart.com/virtual-polyhedra/conway_notation.html - this uses input notation like the other page, but (at least in my browser) when I click "generate" it produces a window that includes what appears to be a list of coordinates of vertices, along with some other things.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is a partial answer. First, try to make find the Conway notation of your polyhedra ([this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg_polyhedron#Construction) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_geodesic_polyhedra_and_Goldberg_polyhedra) will probably help). Now, use http://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/ to make a 3D model of that polyhedra. Finally, use https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/6373/8325 to make a stereographic projection of a wire frame of the 3D model.

So, it doesn't work with every polyhedra, and it requires multiple pieces of software, but it is better than nothing.